# Easy way to send multiple appsettings.json values through worker posting to API in .net core?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, service-worker

I am building a C# Windows Service API polling application in .Net Core 3.1. This will run 24/7 on a server and poll every 5 minutes.

I'd like an easier way to send parameters through my API post call by directly sending values from the body of my appsettings.json instead of creating new classes and strong typing for each object I will be polling.

**My application currently works with one appsettings object given the following code**:

appsettings.json

```
    "ReceiptSettings": {
      "select_topx": "100",
      "tran_type": "REC",
      "sub_type": "PO",
      "max_age_min": "10000",
      "integration_name": "ERP"
    }
```

Worker:

```
        public IConfiguration _configuration { get; private set; }

        ...

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, Task.CompletedTask, TimeSpan.Zero,
                 TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async void DoWork(object state)
        {

            // Keep garbage collector from collecting and stopping timer
            GC.KeepAlive(_timer);

            // Don't let timer execute again if we are still processing last iteration
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locker))
            {
                try
                {
                   RunPoller();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_locker);
                }
            }
        }

        private async void RunPoller()
        {
            var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

            // Do long running work here
            _logger.LogInformation($"Polling started. Iteration: {count}");
            await Task.Run(() => RunPoller.Run(_logger, _apiSettings, _configuration));

        }
```

RunPoller:

```
        public static IConfiguration _iConfiguration { get; private set; }

        public static async Task Run(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptions<APIConfiguration> apiSettings, IConfiguration configuration)
        {

        ...

            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> settings = _config
                    .GetSection("ReceiptSettings")
                    .Get<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_settings);
                var payload = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                ...
            }

        ...
```

**I'd like to refactor it to iterate through a PollingSettings object, creating a new thread for each setting within PollingSettings depending on the values**:

```
"PollingSettings": {
    "ReceiptSettings": {
      "select_topx": "100",
      "tran_type": "REC",
      "sub_type": "PO",
      "max_age_min": "10000",
      "integration_name": "ERP"
    },
    "InventorySettings": {
      "select_topx": "100",
      "tran_type": "IN",
      "sub_type": "ADJ",
      "mark_pickup_id": "1"
    }
```

I have the strongly-typed apiSettings already and can do that. But I'd have to persist a change throughout objects and classes within Visual Studio. If I were to dynamically sending them via this method, then I could open the appsettings.json file in Notepad and modify the parameters in much less time.

I have tried this, but I am getting null value error, and the first iteration doesn't proc the RunPoller class:

```
        private async void DoWork(object state)
        {

            // Keep garbage collector from collecting and stopping timer
            GC.KeepAlive(_timer);

            var pollingConfigs = Configuration.GetSection("PollingSettings").GetChildren();

            // Don't let timer execute again if we are still processing last iteration
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locker))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var setting in pollingConfigs)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> settings = Configuration
                                                               .GetSection(setting.Key)
                                                               .Get<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                        RunPoller(settings);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_locker);
                }
            }
        }

        private async void RunPoller(Dictionary<string, object> settings)
        {

            // Do long running work here
            _logger.LogInformation($"Polling started. Iteration: {count}");
            await Task.Run(() => RunPoller.Run(_logger, _apiSettings, settings));

        }
```

(Persisted the DI for settings to the RunPoller.Run, code is removed for brevity.)

Is there any way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existing code, you could just change the path to get the sub sections, like the following code:
1 - Change the `Key` by `Path` for `.GetSection(setting.Key)` :

```
var pollingConfigs = Configuration.GetSection("PollingSettings").GetChildren();

// Don't let timer execute again if we are still processing last iteration
if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locker))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var setting in pollingConfigs)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> settings = Configuration
                                                   .GetSection(setting.Path)
                                                   .Get<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            RunPoller(settings);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_locker);
    }
}
```

2 - you could also use this solution :
2.1 Get the list of `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
var pollingConfigs = _configuration.GetSection("PollingSettings")
    .GetChildren()
    .Select(y => y.Get<Dictionary<string, object>>());
```

2.2 and in the loop, use directly the values of the list :

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> setting in pollingConfigs)
{
    RunPoller(setting);
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.